# How do I pass a parameter into a C# code-behind method from my aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

For example, right now I have my ASPX like so:

```
...
<tr>
    <td class="label">
        Start Date:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="StartDate" value="<%=GetCurrentDate()%>" maxlength="10" /> <div class="format"><i>(format: mm/dd/yyyy)</i></div>
    </td>
</tr>
...
```

..and my C# as follows:

```
public static string GetCurrentDate()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

This works fine. But what if, for example, I want to pass in a parameter from the ASPX side? Like this:

```
...
<tr>
    <td class="label">
        Start Date:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="StartDate" value="<%=GetCurrentDate("parameter here")%>" maxlength="10" /> <div class="format"><i>(format: mm/dd/yyyy)</i></div>
    </td>
</tr>
...
```

-

```
public static string GetCurrentDate(string val)
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy" + val);
}
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try? `GetCurrentDate("parameter here")`

Comment: <%=GetCurrentDate("testParam")%> returns: 03/08/2017Ae27APara31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are formatting output date wrong.
Please refer to this example:

```
public static string GetCurrentDate(string val)
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + val;
}
```

The " + val" is outside the ToString method.
If you have token parameters in your val, these are changed to DateTime format tokens and the output is what you have published.

Hope this can help.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. This resolves my issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Strings must be enclosed in double quotes in C#, but you can enclosed the attribute value in single quotes in the HTML

Comment: Double-quotes aren't changing anything. I'll edit the original question to make it more clear. <%=GetCurrentDate("testParam")%> returns: 03/08/2017Ae27APara31

Comment: Well, you asked how to call the function, not how to format dates :)